# How to deploy nginx-ingress controller with Helm on k8s, with TCP/UDP load balancing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, udp, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy an nginx-ingress controller on Kubernetes with Helm.

I also want to configure it to bind specific ports of the nginx-ingress-controller service to specific node ports on the VM [I run it inside Vagrant].

For example, I want :

10000 node port -> 8080 nginx-ingress controller -> 10000 udp port of my backend service

My Helm deployment is the following:

```
release_name=tcp-udp-nginx-ic
http_nodePort=30080
https_nodePort=30443

echo
echo "- Installing -${release_name}- into cluster ..." | cowsay

helm del --purge ${release_name}
helm upgrade --install ${release_name} \
--set controller.service.type=NodePort \
--set controller.service.nodePorts.http=${http_nodePort} \
--set controller.service.nodePorts.https=${https_nodePort} \
--set rbac.create=true \
--set controller.replicaCount=1 \
--set controller.resources.requests."memory"=300Mi \
--set controller.resources.requests."cpu"=300m \
--set controller.resources.limits."memory"=300Mi \
--set controller.resources.limits."cpu"=300m \
--set controller.ingressClass=nginx \
--set controller.tcp.configMapNamespace=default \
--set controller.udp.configMapNamespace=default \
--set udp."8080"="default/the-backend-service:10000" \
--set service.nodePorts.udp."8080"=10000 \
stable/nginx-ingress
```

My question is , in what format should I enter the `--set service.nodePorts.udp` part in order to accomplish the above?

The format I am using is referenced in the Helm documentation about the [limitations of --set](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set).

I know I am close because when I clone the chart locally and I set in the `values.yml` file the following, plays well.

```
    nodePorts:
      http: ""
      https: ""
      tcp: {}
#      udp: {}
      udp:
        8080: 10000
        8081: 10001
```

When I deploy it like that and `desscribe` the ingress controller service I get:

```
Name:                     tcp-udp-nginx-ic-nginx-ingress-controller
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=nginx-ingress
                          chart=nginx-ingress-1.24.3
                          component=controller
                          heritage=Tiller
                          release=tcp-udp-nginx-ic
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=nginx-ingress,component=controller,release=tcp-udp-nginx-ic
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.109.1.182
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30080/TCP
Endpoints:
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30443/TCP
Endpoints:
Port:                     8080-udp  8080/UDP
TargetPort:               8080-udp/UDP
NodePort:                 8080-udp  10000/UDP
Endpoints:

Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: Bounty or no bounty, this is off-topic. Try ServerFault.

Answer (score -1):

Move your complex `--set` settings into a custom `myvalues.yaml`. You don't have to clone the chart to use a yaml file to override chart values.

When you run `helm upgrade --install ${release_name} -f myvalues.yaml stable/nginx-ingress` it will override any default values with the values configured in this file.